# How to be sure that my MVC project is running on the correct version after upgrade to vs2010?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I just installed visual studio 2010 and upgraded my MVC project (which was running on MVC RC2 in visual studio 2008).
visual studio 2010 updated every project file to target the framework 4.0.
But the system.web.dll is pointing to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC
>   2\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll

in VS2010 object browser, I have every dll showing up in multiple versions as expected (3.5.0.0 and 4.0.0.0) except for the System.Web.Mvc dll which doesn't show any version and points to the path I mentioned above.

Isn't this namespace point to the Framework folder like the System.Web namespace?

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.dll

Comment: thanks for the typo editing Joe :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MVC 2 uses the *same binary* for .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0.](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/03/html-encoding-nuggets-aspnetmvc2.aspx)

Comment: yes, but I never installed the Release version, so did it update the binaries when I installed vs2010? or Am I still using RC2...

Comment: If recall correctly, installing VS2010 should also update older versions of MVC 2. Maybe you can right click the System.Web.Mvc.dll in Explorer, choose Properties and go to the Details tab. What File Version do you see there? I'm using MVC 2 RTM and my version is 2.0.50217.0.

Comment: Check the version number. RC 2 is 2.0.50129.0. Release is 50217, like @Kristof said.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed :). And that's right it was updated when installing the RTM.